# Mongo Connection status in Log

Tags: mongodb

```
[initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59781 #265 (99 connections now open)
```

1) What is #265?

2) The connection count doesn't increase above 99. Where to configure. What does it represents?

Answer (score 1):

1) #265 is the "rank" of the connected user, there were 264 connections before him.
2) Watch this page : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/
   I think that *uri.maxPoolSize* could be increased to go over 99 connections